# Child and parent processes communicating asynchronously linux

Tags: c++, linux, asynchronous, input, fork

How does one create a fork and continue without waiting for the other one to finish? I have written a sample program to illustrate my issue.

The program has a counting program which just counts up from zero and prints the next number every second continuously. This is the parent side of the program, and the client sits around continuously waiting for user input. When the user inputs a number the counting number becomes this number, because the variables are shared. Here is the code

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   // Declaration for exit()

using namespace std;

struct Timer {
    int GetTimeMilli()
    {
        gettimeofday( &end,NULL);
        return int( (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec )*1000) +
                int( (end.tv_usec- 
        start.tv_usec)/1000);
    }

    Timer()
    {
        ResetTimer();
    }
    //reset timer so start time becomes current time
    void ResetTimer()
    {
        gettimeofday( &start,NULL);
    }   
private:
    struct timeval start, end;


};

int num = 0;

int main()
{
    char* name = new char[256];

   pid_t pID = vfork();

   if (pID == 0) // child
   {
      // Code only executed by child process

      printf( "child process: \n");
      while(1)
      {
        cin.getline( name,20 );
        num = atoi( name);
      }
    }
    else if (pID < 0)            // failed to fork
    {
        cerr << "Failed to fork" << endl;
        exit(1);
        // Throw exception
    }
    else // parent
    {
      // Code only executed by parent process
        printf( "parent process:\n");
        Timer a;
        while(1)
        {

            if( a.GetTimeMilli() > 1000.0f )
            {
                a.ResetTimer();
                printf("%d\n",num);
                num++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Code executed by both parent and child.





    delete[] name;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*because the variables are shared*" - There's your problem, right there. Variables are **not** shared after a `fork()`. For this problem, you are better off using [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).

Comment: exactly what I was looking for thanks. another question, I want the user to be able to type into the console, without the console output obscuring what the user is typing in if it prints while the user is typing. How could I go about this?

Comment: Can you take a step back and tell us what you are trying to accomplish? Forget about processes and threads and asynchronous input, just tell us what your program does. To paraphrase a famous quote, "So you've got a problem, and you've decided to solve it threads. Now you've got two problems."

Comment: basically I am writing server code which will print out server information like no of hosts, no of client requests etc. I also want a command prompt interaction where you can pull data and set variables, without blocking the program.
However, after reconsidering, to be honest, I may edit it so it does not automatically print anything, and you have to type a command to pull information.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't [`wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wait.html) for the child process in the parent process, the child will become a so called [zombie process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process), and will continue to linger in the system for as long as the parent process lives.

If you don't want to block in the parent process, you can use [`waitpid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/waitpid.html) with the `WNOHANG` option to poll.

Comment: It will only be a zombie for as long as the parent proc exists. After that the zombie child will be reaped by init.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing is, I want the child process to be there all the time the parent lives though. Basically the actual program I want to run is a server where there is an application running continuously, printing out data. A child of the application takes user input to set and get variables from the program; I don't know how to make a non blocking input, so the idea is the child interacts with the program without blocking it to wait for input.